# Find with absolute path inside a bashscript | xargs basename

Tags: shell-script, find, xargs, basename

I have to find recursively inside a bash script. Since I can invoke the bash script from anywhere, I am forced to use the absolute path. Sometimes the absolute path can get very long, and the output get's tedious in the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find /long/absolute/path -type f | sort
```

So I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find /long/absolute/path -type f | xargs -L 1 -I @ echo $(basename @) | sort
```

But this doesn't gives the basename. Could you please find out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You went wrong in two ways:

1. You're passing semi-arbitrary filenames from `find` through *two* pipes -- to `xargs` and then on to `sort`.  Use null-terminated `-print0` from `find`, if you're able, or embed the actions inside `-exec`, [as maulinglawns demonstrated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469620/117549).
2. **IF** you had filenames that never contained any characters from `$IFS`, your command would still fail because you've asked `xargs` to execute echo with a command substitution; that command substitution asks `basename` to output the base name of `@`, which probably doesn't exist. Closer would have been:

   ```
   find /long/absolute/path -type f | xargs -L 1 -I @ basename @ | sort
   ```

... as that would have allowed `xargs` to interpolate the filenames as arguments to `basename`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you suggest that `probably @ didn't exists`? The above script file in the question does print out the filenames although with the absolute path, implying that `@` is not blank

Comment: when you used command substitution, it ran before xargs filled in `@`, so basename was looking for a file named exactly `@`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
find /some/long/path/ -type f -exec basename {} \;| sort
```

Comment: This works. Is `\;` necessary? Any idea why mine didn't work?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. Without it you get `find: missing argument to '-exec'`. I don't know why your variant didn't work, I rarely use `xargs` myself.

Comment: be aware of arbitrary filenames being passed from `find` through the pipe to `sort` --- `touch $'/some/long/path/foo\nbar'` ---> `bar` on one line, `foo` on the next.